# Hiding a PHP JSON output from showing in view source

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to hide my JSON php output in view source, I am working with amCharts and have created PHP data sources that pull the data from a mySQL database and format it to JSON format so that amcharts can read it. Is it possible to hide the formatted JSON data in view source and still have amcharts read it.

My PHP code below. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'VPM2014' )
or die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );


// Select the data base
$db = mysql_select_db( 'vpm_global', $link ) or die ( 'Error selecting database    \'vpm_global\' : ' . mysql_error() );

// Fetch the data
$query = "SELECT Price_date, ZAR_Based_1000 FROM gso ORDER BY Price_date ASC";
$result = mysql_query( $query );

// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
// Nope
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die( $message );
}

$prefix = '';
echo "[\n";
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
echo $prefix . " {\n";
echo '  "date": "' . $row['Price_date'] . '",' . "\n";
echo '  "value": ' . $row['ZAR_Based_1000'] . '' . "\n";
echo " }";
$prefix = ",\n";
}
echo "\n]";

// Close the connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to hide the source ***and*** provide your charts with JSON data. If you don't output the JSON, your charts won't have any data.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to hide the JSON data and provide the chart would be to create the chart server-side as, say an image, and use HTML to display that image to the user.

Because the chart library you are using is client side javascript, the JSON must also be available to the client and thus visible to the browser using 'View Source' or other DOM debug tools.

Comment: Thanks, would it possible to hide the folder that contains the .php files from public viewing. Just out of interest.

Comment: @jasonh That won't work if the PHP file is generating the chart image. The file in question will have to be publically accessible, as you will be linking to it like so: `<img src="chart.php?t=1&etc=34" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really send data to client and expect you still have a control over what he does with it. You can only make it a tiny bit harder to steal the data. Like by checking HTTP Refere header. Or by scaring the client with a warning about legal stuff and going to court etc. But still, none of these will stop more then 20% of internet population from eventual successful thief.

The only true solution would be, like others said, to not send him these data. Like, to generate the chart on the server (somehow) and send to the client only result as a picture. That way he won't get the raw data, just the graph visualization (at least until he hacks your server).